# Proof any harmonic function is the real part of a holomorphic function

Tags: calculus, analysis

in a book I'm currently reading, they propose the following construction to construct a holomorphic function from a harmonic function u. (here we are on a simply connected domain):
We define: v(z) = $\int$ -$u_{y}$ dx + $u_{x}$dy where the integral is over an arbitrary path (by connecting a fixed point $z_{0}$ and z).

Specifically, I do not understand their claim that F = u + iv satisfies the Cauchy-Riemann equations. For me, in order to verify $u_{x}$ = $v_{y}$ this would have to mean that $\int$ $u_{y}$ dx derived in respect to y is zero since $\int$ $u_{x}$dy derived in respect to y is already $u_{x}$ . Why is that?